# Canvas setMatrix and concat with identity matrix behaves different

Tags: java, android

It's my code.
I obviously make matrix to identity, so regardless of using `concat` or `setMatrix`, result must be same.

This is my code:

```
@Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    matrix.reset();

    Log.d("matrix1 : " + canvas.getMatrix());
    canvas.concat(matrix);
    Log.d("matrix2 : " + canvas.getMatrix());

    if (backgroundBitmap != null) {
      canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }

    if(bitmap != null) {
      canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmapPaint);
      canvas.drawPath(path, drawPathPaint);
    }

    if (drawGuide && touchMove) {
      canvas.drawLine(0, y, getWidth(), y, guidePaint);
      canvas.drawLine(x, 0, x, getHeight(), guidePaint);
    }
  }
```

[When I use concat:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdocu.png)

[When I use setMatrix(I expect that it translate half height):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdUbj.png)

The most strange one is that toString result was same on both case.

`06-02 17:46:26.502 5712-5712/kr.iplab.doodlr.debug D/DOODLR: CanvasView.onDraw() --- matrix1 : Matrix{[1.0, 0.0, 0.0][0.0, 1.0, 0.0][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}`

`06-02 17:46:26.502 5712-5712/kr.iplab.doodlr.debug D/DOODLR: CanvasView.onDraw() --- matrix2 : Matrix{[1.0, 0.0, 0.0][0.0, 1.0, 0.0][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}`

I can make my program work well by using concat but I'm so curious about this. What's going on?

Comment: if you concat an identity matrix the result will be the same, thats why your `Log.d` shows the same

Comment: @pskink Yes I know it, Strange one I meant was matrix is same but result is different.